# CakePHP export html/data to PowerPoint Format

Tags: php, cakephp, powerpoint

I am facing a problem with CakePHP 2.X. My client wants to export some data generated from a mysql database, to a powerpoint (.ppt or .pptx) format(s) in a specific template. I allready knew the PHPPowerPoint is at the alpha status so I don't want to make a plugin for Cake based on this. I also found
[this](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-com-powerpoint/)! little gem but It works only for Windows PHP and I am using a linux based server (CentOs).

It is possible to create an xml or an html, encoded with something compatible of powerpoint format and just put the right php headers at the top? And what is this something?

or a better solution is there an api or a plugin something to work for all the platforms?
And could this plugin or api is compatible for Cake?

Thank you

Comment: No one?? Someone is getting up votes!!

Comment: Suggestion: creating pdf as presentation. You can use pdf as substitute for ppt, and is much easier to create.

Comment: I suggest the same thing to my client and this is probably the way we are going to proceed but it is not a solution of making dynamic powerpoint presentations. Btw thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

PHPPowerPoint seem to be at a good place now, check out their GitHub: [PHPPowerpoint](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint)

Installation instructions: http://phppowerpoint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html